# Replace newline in python when reading line for line

Tags: python, regex, newline, python-2.x

I am trying to do a simple parsing on a text in python which I have no issues with in bash using tr '\n' ' '.  Basically to get all of the lines on a single line. In python print line is a bit different from what I understand.  re.sub cannot find my new line because it doesn't exist even though when I print to an output it does.  Can someone explain how I can work around this issue in python?

Here is my code so far:

```
# -*- iso-8859-1 -*-
import re
def proc():
    f= open('out.txt', 'r')
    lines=f.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        line = line.strip()
        if '[' in line:
            line_1 = line
            line_1_split = line_1.split(' ')[0]
            line_2 = re.sub(r'\n',r' ', line_1_split)
            print line_2
proc()
```

Edit:  I know that "print line," will print without the newline. The issue is that I need to handle these lines both before and after doing operations line by line. My code in shell uses sed, awk and tr to do this.

Comment: `line.strip()` removes _all_ leading & trailing whitespace, including the `\n`. BTW, if you want to process line by line it's better to do `for line in f:` rather than reading the whole file into a list with `readlines` and then iterating over the list.

Comment: `print` adds a newline to the end of the output. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/493386/2800918

Comment: @CAB make sense

Answer (score 1):

You can write directly to stdout to avoid the automatic newline of `print`:

```
from sys import stdout
stdout.write("foo")
stdout.write("bar\n")
```

This will print `foobar` on a single line.

Comment: I think this is the best answer.  No pretty but it seems most efficient

Answer (score 1):

When you call the `print` statement, you automatically add a new line. Just add a comma:

```
print line_2,
```

And it will all print on the same line.

Mind you, if you're trying to get all lines of a file, and print them on a single line, there are more efficient ways to do this:

```
with open('out.txt', 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        line = line.strip()
        # Some extra line formatting stuff goes here
        print line, # Note the comma!
```

Alternatively, just join the lines on a string:

```
everything_on_one_line = ''.join(i.strip() for i in f.readlines())
print everything_on_one_line
```

Comment: This works for the core problem but it isn't easy to handle operations on each line before and after.

Answer (score 1):

Using `with` ensures you close the file after iteration.

Iterating saves memory and doesn't load the entire file.

`rstrip()` removes the newline in the end.

Combined:

```
with open('out.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        print line.rstrip(),
```

Comment: This works but then you have to print to something and it isn't useful afterwards.  It would be nice if I could var = print line, but it doesn't work taht way

Answer (score 0):

Use `replace()` method.

```
file = open('out.txt', 'r')
data = file.read()
file.close()
data.replace('\n', '')
```

Comment: This doesn't solve the issue. There weren't any lines in the string to begin with, so replacing won't do anything. The problem actually lies in the print statement.

Comment: In python3 it's possible to use `print('text', end='')` to escape new line.

Comment: This isn't python 3 though, it's python 2. The answer still misses the problem in the question.